# Yii2 AutoCompleate дубляж ввода текста?

Tags: yii2

Есть форма поиска, первый и второй инпут я использую [виджет](http://demos.krajee.com/widget-details/typeahead#advanced-usage) от *картика* `kartik\typeahead\Typeahead;`.

Когда я пытаюсь найти эвакуатор, то у меня происходит дубляж, я бы хотел от него избавится.

Сам пример как выглядит:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это таблица где юзеры сохраняют свою специальность

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
controller`public function actionCategoryList($q = null)
{
    $query = new Query();

    $query->select('title')
        ->from('profile_has_category')
        ->where('title LIKE "%' . $q . '%"')
        ->orderBy('title');
    $command = $query->createCommand();
    $data = $command->queryAll();
    $out = [];
    foreach ($data as $d) {
        $out[] = ['value' => $d['title']];
    }
    echo Json::encode($out);
}
```

***View***

```
Typeahead::widget([
                'name' => 'Search[category]',
                'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Искать специальности ...'],
                'pluginOptions' => ['highlight' => true],
                'class' => 'search-input-spec',
                'dataset' => [
                    [
                        'datumTokenizer' => "Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('value')",
                        'display' => 'value',
                        //'prefetch' => $asset->baseUrl . '/samples/countries.json',
                        'remote' => [
                            'url' => Url::to(['search/category-list']) . '?q=%QUERY',
                            'wildcard' => '%QUERY'
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что выбираешь, то и выдает. Скорее всего нужно выбирать `DISTINCT` (используется для возврата только разных значений из таблицы):

```
$query->select('title')
      ->distinct()
      ->from('profile_has_category')
      ...
      ...
      // и т.д.
```